# Can't Change Font Color With CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div class = "left">
<div id = "links">
<a href = "none" style = "text-decoration: none"><b>About</b></a>
<br>
<a href = "none" style = "text-decoration: none"><b>Principals</b></a>
<br>
<a href = "none" style = "text-decoration: none"><b>Contact</b></a>    
<br>    
</div>
</div>​
```

and CSS

```
.left {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       width: 30%;
       height: 100%;
       background-color: #8EE5EE;
       color: #000000;
      }
#links {
        position: relative;
        top: 40%;
        text-align: right;
        font-family: "Verdana", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #000000;
       }​
```

The color of my links should be black, but they are appearing as dark blue.  What's wrong with this code?

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VHnnA/6/)

Thanks!

Comment: The `#links`identifies the div and not the links within the div (`<a>`) tags. By changing the color, you are only changing the color of the text within the div not the color of the anchor tag text. One of the numerous answers below can provide you with the right solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `a` elements have a default style which doesn't inherit the color from the parent element. To force the inheritance of the `color` property:

```
a {
    color: #000; /* for browsers that don't support 'inherit' as a color value */
    color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your css:

```
#links a:link{
    color: #000;
}
```

You can then add things like...

```
#links a:visited{
    color: #000;
}
#links a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
#links a:active{
    color: #000;
}
```

...to change the color of the link in different states as well.

Some reading material on this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 2):

Add `#links a { color: #000; }` to your CSS to style your links (or just `a { color: #000; }` if you want this color to be global).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#links a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
   color: #000000;
}
```

Heres some [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp).